# In SSL two-way authentication, how exactly do client and server certificates authenticate each other?

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

Now most of the SSL authentication is implemented directly through third-party libraries, suddenly I want to know the two-way authentication, the client and server exactly how to use the information inside their respective certificates for authentication. For example, we have client certificates and server certificates, and we have extracted the contents of both certificates. How can we determine whether the authentication is successful or not?

Comment: SSL is described in excruciating detail in many places.

Comment: stackoverflow is typically not the place to ask such tutorial questions.

Comment: However many of those places are wrong @davenewton. Try RFC 2616, or the excellent book by Eric Rescoria. If the authentication fails you will get an error or an exception, depending on language and API.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic and too broad. Such kind of questions are better asked at [security.se] and there are also answers for this, like [SSL Certificate framework 101: How does the browser actually verify the validity of a given server certificate?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56389/) and [How to validate a client certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48802/). I recommend to study the existing questions and answers there and then ask the remaining details you did not understood yet at [security.se].